# advice on using php to loop through multiple FTP connections

Tags: php

I am looking for some advice on how other developers would go about completing this same task.  Essentially what I am attempting to do is loop through rows within my database to connect to multiple FTP accounts, preg_match, then output the files separate from each other. Here is an example of the workflow:

```
pull connection 1
login to FTP
check preg_match against all files listed
list matching files
disconnect
...
pull connection 2
login to FTP
check preg_match against all files listed
list matching files
disconnect
...
repeat
```

The end result will be me creating a table with the results separate from each other.

Answer (score 1):

I think the largest challenge here will be the latency time. I would look for a solution which didn't attempt to do this all in real-time, while someone was waiting for a web page to load or some other output. If possible I would build some API on the remote servers so I didn't have to do raw FTP requests, but could instead query for the matched results as determined on the remote server. If needed, though, I would use PHP's cURL facility to make the connection to each external server independently, in it's own cron-driven script, with all output stored into a central database. Then the final output needed could be queried against the local database independently of fetching/matching.

Comment: Well it will be connecting to many different clients so an API would not really be an option as they could not all set it up.  latency times wont be an issue though as a timeout can simply result in a error message which is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If there are many FTP connections to make and if performance is a consideration then you will want to make the connections in parallel rather than serially. To do this, spawn sub-processes that do the  work, saving their results into a DB while the parent process waits for enough results to be created before getting the results from the DB and outputting them.